# How to use gsub with special characters

Tags: lua, gsub, lua-patterns

it seems as if when I add a special character gsub no longer works for me.

how can I use text with such characters

```
 print(string.gsub("a !foo walking", "%a+",{
   ["!foo"] = "bar",
   }))
```

Desired output

```
"a bar walking"
```

Comment: Try `"%S+"` if you need to match all non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 2):

`%a` matches letters only.

To match any non-whitespace characters, you can use `%S`:

```lua
print(string.gsub("a !foo walking", "%S+",{
   ["!foo"] = "bar",
}))
```

See an [online Lua demo](https://ideone.com/q4EiGy).

Comment: Thanks so much this was the solution I needed can believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

**Version 1:**

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

text = 'a !foo walking'
subbed = string .gsub( text, '!foo', 'bar' )

print( subbed )
```

**Version 2:**
same thing as before, just use `:` instead of `.`
so your text becomes first arg in gsub() function

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

text = 'a !foo walking'
subbed = text :gsub( '!foo', 'bar' )

print( subbed )
```